# Check table names of other users

Tags: oracle, exception

I'm in a data migration and i've been request to check some table names, i don't have DBA permissions and the USER_TABLE view is not useful because the tables are from other user. So my idea is to make a a query like this (i'm using oracle sql developer):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_exist (NAME VARCHAR(50), EXIST VARCHAR(15))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
/
DECLARE
v_exist number;

BEGIN
SELECT (1) INTO v_exist FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE ROWNUM =1;
INSERT INTO table_exist (NAME, EXIST)
VALUES ('TABLE','EXIST');

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
INSERT INTO table_exist (NAME, EXIST)
VALUES ('TABLE','NOT_EXIST');
END;
/
SELECT * FROM table_exist;
/
DROP TABLE table_exist;
```

The issue is that when the table don't exist sql ignore the exception block here is the error i get:

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 5, columna 55:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
ORA-06550: línea 5, columna 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

no se ha seleccionado ninguna fila



Table TABLE_EXIST borrado.
```

Can you tell me why i get this error and why sql don't read the exception block? (i don´t have too much experience in sql oracle).

Thaks, i hope you can help me.

Comment: That's a compilation error and won't be catched by the exception. If you want to try this approach you'll need dynamic sql. Look for `execute immediate`

Comment: Forget it, this approach won't work anyways since you are not going to know if table doesn't exists or you don't have access to it. If you do have access to it with your user try to query `select owner, table_name from all_tables where owner ='theOtherSchema';`

Comment: vercelli, ty a lot it works!

Answer (score 1):

There are three versions of various catalog views: DBA_, USER_, and ALL_. What you need to query is `ALL_TABLES` (not `USER_TABLES` which only shows you your own tables, and not `DBA_TABLES` since you don't have DBA powers). `ALL_TABLES` will show you all the tables you have been granted permission to see, including from other users.

Perhaps some of the tables you "need" to see you won't be able to see, because you don't have the necessary permissions. That would be a sign that there is a mismatch between what you were asked to do and the powers you were given; there will be no "technological" way around it, it would become a business issue.

Comment: Ty a lot!! i do it with select owner, table_name from all_tables and it works!